# Back and forth communication between Pico and PC

Tags: python, usb, pi-pico, micropython

I am making a Pico powered PWM fan controller, and I currently have 2 potentiometers to control the fan speed. I am however thinking about writing some software in Python to modify the speed. The biggest issue I see with it, is the transfer of data from software to the Pico (how to send and receive). How do I do this?

Comment: You can use any of the methods available for talking to a microcontroller.  The Pico is not special in this regard.

Comment: Basic serial work fine (sometimes incorrectly called rs-232). Usually I use a usb-to-3v3 volt serial cable.

Comment: @NomadMaker So then I use UART on both sides as the interface I program in?

Comment: You have to make sure that the voltages line up, but precisely that.